# Starting a Docker container with a user different from the one on the host

Tags: linux, bash, docker, ubuntu, debian

I am trying to deploy an image on a Ubuntu server. The problem is I would like the container to have a user other than root. In other words, I would like to start the container under that user.

What I have tried.
I have successfully created a user in my container which has an image.
I tried to start the container with the docker start command which was unsuccessful.

I tried to create a new container with a user defined inside the dockerfile, it was also unsuccessful.

```
root@juju_dev_server:/home/dev# sudo docker run -it --user dev d08d53c4d78b
docker: Error response from daemon: linux spec user: unable to find user dev: no matching entries in passwd file
```

.

Here is my dockerfile

```
 FROM debian

RUN groupadd -g 61000 dev
RUN useradd -g 61000 -l -m -s /bin/false -u 61000 dev
USER dev

CMD ["bash"]



FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /target/juju-0.0.1.jar juju-0.0.1.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","juju-0.0.1.jar"]
```

Comment: Explain the -1. The question is very clear.

Comment: @Claudio The correction is not right. user defined and user-defined are not the same this.  first one is noun and a verb. The second is a single noun.

Answer (score 1):

How I've done it, I use Alpine not Ubuntu but it should work fine:

Creating and running as a user called "developer"

Dockerfile

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "adduser -D -u 1000 developer"
RUN passwd -d developer

RUN chown -R developer /home/developer/.bash*

RUN echo "developer    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/developer

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bash"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
# stuff I need running as root here. Then below runs a bash shell as "developer"
sudo -u developer -H bash -c "$@;"
```

I suppose you'll want to change your ENTRYPOINT to CMD or similar, or write it into your entrypoint.sh however you like to launch your java stuff.

Comment: The user developer is it going to be created? on the host or the container ?

Comment: Nothing that is defined in `Dockerfile` is doing anything on the host (with the exception of mounted volumes of course).

Comment: I still keep getting: no matching entries in passwd file. When attempting to run the following command:  sudo docker run -it --user developer d08d53c4d78b

Comment: @DannyB except it is though, it has been a long time since I wrote it so I can't remember all the logic behind how I implemented it. But it works perfectly for me.

Comment: @NesanMano what does running docker logs {container_name} give you when you try to run it? And it'll create the user developer on the container. Also you shouldn't need to specify --user or anything like that if you use the entrypoint code provided.

Comment: @Shardj Thanks for your help, it is working as intended. The mistake was on my side, I had to change the order in which the script blocks were placed in docker file.  Since I had another block for java with from java8 mention, that block had to come before RUN adduser and etc

Comment: @NesanMano glad it's working for you, if you could mark this as the accepted answer I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The Dockerfile you show creates two images.  The first one is a plain `debian` image with a non-root user.  The second one ignores the first one and is a somewhat routine Java image.

You need to do these two steps in the same image.  If I was going to write your Dockerfile it might look like

```sh
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080

# (Prefer COPY to ADD unless you explicitly want its
# auto-unpacking semantics.)
COPY /target/juju-0.0.1.jar juju-0.0.1.jar

# Set up a non-root user context, after COPYing content
# in.  (Prevents the application from overwriting
# itself as a useful security measure.)
RUN groupadd -g 61000 app
RUN useradd -g 61000 -l -m -s /bin/false -u 61000 app
USER app

# Set the main container command.  (Generally prefer
# CMD to ENTRYPOINT if you’re only using one; it makes
# both getting debugging shells and later adopting the
# pattern of an initializing entrypoint script easier.)
CMD ["java","-jar","juju-0.0.1.jar"]
```